# Daily Data subset of main database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a large Db 500GB one of our customers wants daily snapshot of only his data, He only has a 3mb connection , I suspect that is the Max !  What method is the most effective method I could use?
    1. Views that are updated but it wants the underlaying tables.
    2. Replication I don’t know much about this.
    3. Alternative method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge replication, which allows you to [initialize a subscriber without using a snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152488.aspx). You will have to initialize replication on the subscriber from a backup. You can possibly do the same with transactional replication, but it just never worked quite the same for me. YMMV. When it breaks (etc.) you will have to be prepared to ship a new backup and start over (hacking replication sometimes works, but don't count on it). Changing database structures is also a pain once in replication. I have seen ~500Gb with less than 3Mbit work in production, though not without proper planning and preparation (and grey hair)

I have used transactional replication with a read only subscription, where I invoked the distribution with a batch file on a task schedule once a day. Transactional replication did not feel as maintained (from MS) or as stable as merge replication, though the data integrity with transactional was more consistent

I have not tried transaction log shipping, but that might also be an option

(p.s. notice I didn't say "If it breaks")